# Как запретить вставку записей в таблицу?

Tags: delphi, база-данных

В программе на Delphi есть таблицы, в которые данные копируются из других таблиц, а потом редактируются. Как сделать, что бы после копирования данных в такую таблицу новые записи нельзя было вставить вручную? Т.е. когда редактируется самая нижняя запись и нажимается стрелка вниз на клавиатуре, то не появлялась бы новая запись.

Answer (score 1):

Выставьте вашему гриду `ReadOnly := True;`

Answer (score 0):

Придумайте идентификатор и отлавливайте его.

Не ясно что за СУБД, у FireBird есть удобная SQL команда InsertOrUpdate

Answer (score 0):

Бедняга, вас тоже в поисковиках забанили? :) Простите за сарказм, и [**ловите ответ**](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=Delphi+отучить+DBGrid+вставлять+новую+запись).
И сразу же [**первая ссылка**](http://delphiworld.narod.ru/base/dbgrid_not_autoadd_new_record.html).